# unable to load R libraries in R 3.2.2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've recently downloaded R 3.2.2 and RStudio to a Windows 7 64 bit pc. I am able to install packages but cannot install libraries such as ggplot2 and dplyr afterward.

When I attempt to install a library I receive the error below:

```
Error in get(method, envir = home) : 
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/dm/Documents/R/R-3.2.2/library/digest/R/digest.rdb': No such file or directory
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In .registerS3method(fin[i, 1], fin[i, 2], fin[i, 3], fin[i, 4],  :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In get(method, envir = home) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’
```

I tried using `install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)` as mentioned in another post but the problem persists. I also tried changing the CRAN mirror, but to no avail.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What packages were you able to install?

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to say that you can install a package just fine (with e.g. `install.packages('ggplot2)`), but that you can't load the packages (with e.g. `library(ggplot2)`)?